# Fastlane setup - fatal: could not read Password for 'https://<org>@dev.azure.com': terminal prompts disabled

Tags: ios, git, code-signing, fastlane

I am trying to setup Fastlane for iOS certificates and profile syncing in my MacBook. When I execute the command `sudo fastlane match development --readonly`, I get below error.

[image]

What is it actually? I guess that the terminal is blocking the prompt where I could enter the match password. I do not understand why I face this issue, also I have access to the repository.

Comment: Try cloning the certs repo seperately and see if you have the access to it. Do check via SSH

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the password would be cached in your Credential Storage (osxkeychain on Mac), but for your current user.
And you are executing that command as `root`.

Check:

- if you have a credential helper set (with your account)

  ```
    git config credential.helper
  ```
- if your credentials are stored

  ```
    git ls-remote https://...
    # if a popup is displayed, enter your credentials there
  ```
- if the same command would work if executed as you (instead of `root`)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have used ssh with the old macbook, are you trying now with https ?

Btw, it is not recommended to use the local fastlane, see [Bundler](https://bundler.io).